# Unable to teardown temporary file used by Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas, file-permissions, temporary-files

My unittest teardown code does not remove the file

> test_utility1.dat

I even tried os.remove and also no luck. I don't understand why my process is holding on to the file after raising an error. I am running this on python 3.6 and using Pycharm as my IDE. All my tests passed, except the teardown.

i mean i tried to mock, but i had no luck (newbie, and i just could not understand or grasp the concept). So i had to result to creating a temporary file and deleting it. I had the same problem, so i thought it will work better if i tried the *textfixture* library. but same error.

**UPDATED MY POST**

- i have created a file directly on the os called *test_utility1.dat*
- removed the old post which showed my temporary file creation
- still the same result.

Please help. thank you

**protoype7.py**

```
import sys
import pandas

def create_utility_config_dataframe(a):

cols = ['Name', 'D', 'L', 'J', 'H', 'E', 'M', 'RF', 'AF']
try:
    return pandas.read_csv(a, sep='\t', usecols=cols)

except Exception as ve:
    ve = (str(ve) + "\n\nPlease ensure utility config '%s' exist and is correctly formatted (tab delimited)" %a)
    sys.exit(ve)
```

**test2_prototype7.py**

```
from prototype7 import create_utility_config_dataframe
import os
import unittest

class TestCreateUtilityConfigDataFrame(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        os.remove('test_utility1.dat')

    def test_when_parameters_is_invalid(self):

        self.assertRaises(SystemExit, create_utility_config_dataframe,'test_utility1.dat')
```

**errorlog**

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test_utility1.dat'
```

**test_utility1.dat**

```
Name.D.L.J.H.E.M.RF.AF
line1.150.4.2.150.2.Copper.1.true
```

Comment: have you tried a context manager around the `clf.file.write`stuff, or did you try closing the files after writing? It might be that the file you are trying to tear down is still open due to the setUp function and thus blocks the closing permission

Comment: there is no close for this `cls.file.write` . I even tried the normal create a file & close. Also same issue.
this cleanup error only occurs for the test that uses `test_utility1.dat`

Comment: Could you try to condense the irrelevant stuff in your code to reproduce the error? Write a minimal setUp function, throw away unnecessary tests. This should also help you and us to find a solution quicker

Comment: i will edit my post to reflect that

Comment: i did exactly as you mentioned @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: You are constructing file before the setup function, but you are not tearing down file, but a new TempDirectory Object. Maybe this causes the error. Additonally, I'd think (being also a newb in python testing) that the file construction should take place in the setUp class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152022/discussion-between-dean-and-quickbeam2k1).

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 i tired to move that inside the setup. same error. i can post the new code if you need

Comment: Check `TempDirectory.cleanup_all()` in your teardown function. There is nothing like a `file.cleanup_all()`! call. Additionally, now new TempDirectory object is instantiated

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 i cannot use that under the teardown function. it says it is not defined. Also this is from the `from testfixtures import TempDirectory`

Comment: without actually solving your problem, did you consider [pytest for tempdirectories](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html). On another note, did you try `cls.file.cleanup_all()`?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 i have updated my post, to show that this happens even when assessing the file directly which already exist. i am just running a test and deleting the file. it still does not let go. my suspicion is pandas.read_csv when value error it is not letting go maybe?

Comment: hmm, this is strange. this would imply that reading the csv on one line and directly deleting it on the next line, e.g. in a jupyter notebook, will fail. Have you tried that? By the way, is the indentation of prototype7.py correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the resolution is below.

**initial code snippet**

```
self.assertRaises(SystemExit, create_utility_config_dataframe, a)
```

**new code snippet**

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
     create_utility_config_dataframe(a)
```

this solved the problem. it is an issue with the `assertRaise` code. I am not entirely sure why, but if i use the `with` statement it works fine now.